# Creating a JAX-WS service without a WSDL

Tags: jax-ws

It seems you can obtain a JAX-WS (2.2) [`Service`](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jaxws-api/2.2/javax/xml/ws/WebServiceFeature.html) in a number of ways, either by constructing one or using one of the static `create` methods. Any alternative that requires a WSDL location as a parameter makes sense to me because the WSDL provides all the necessary information to build a service, but what is the intended purpose/usage of the [create methods that don't accept a WSDL](https://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/jaxws-api/2.2/javax/xml/ws/Service.html#create(javax.xml.namespace.QName))? Such as:

```
public static Service create(javax.xml.namespace.QName serviceName)
```

Answer (score 0):

The [JAX-WS reference implementation documentation about the Dispatch API](https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.6/docs/ch03.html#users-guide-dispatch) provides some insight:

> The `javax.xml.ws.Service` acts as a factory for the creation of a dynamic Service. When created for use with `Dispatch<T>` APIs the `Service` created can be either a `Service` that has knowledge of the binding information of a known `Service` or no knowledge of any specific `Service`.
>
> If the Service has been created with WSDL binding information, the port need not be added as the `Dispatch<T>` instance will be created specific for the binding information provided in the supplied WSDL file.

...and if you don't create the `Service` with a WSDL then it is mandatory to add a "port" programtically, like this for example:

```
service.addPort(QName portName, String SOAPBinding.SOAP12HTTP_BINDING, String endpointAddress);
```

So in conclusion, I think creating a `Service` without a WSDL is available so you can build up the service yourself when you don't have a WSDL and want to use the JAX-WS `Dispatch` API.